# joomla module position else if

Tags: php, joomla

I am making a responsive joomla template,
but i am stucked in a problem.

i have four module position: header1, header2, header3, header4
if there is only position active , then its class will be 'col12' & 'last'

if two position then class will be 'col6' for both position and class 'last' only for last position

if there position then class 'three' for all positions and class 'last' for the last position

how do i do this in array ??
any good solution for doing this

currently i am using this but not working properly
or please tell me the block system that was used in JAT3 framework
how can i make my own block system for my template like jat3

```
if($header1 && $header2 && $header3 && $header4 > 0){
    $hCols='three';
}elseif($header1 && $header2 && $header3 > 0){
    $hCols='four';
    $h3last='last';
}elseif($header1 && $header2 > 0){
    $hCols='six';
    $h2last='last';
}elseif($header1 > 0){
    $hCols='twelve';
    $h1last='last';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to check that all the values are not null (I'd prefer using `isset`) - but you're actually checking only the last value in every `if`, you can do:

```
if($header1 > 0 && $header2 > 0 && $header3 > 0 && $header4 > 0){
    $hCols='three';
}elseif($header1 > 0 && $header2 > 0 && $header3 > 0){
    $hCols='four';
    $h3last='last';
}elseif($header1 > 0 && $header2 > 0){
    $hCols='six';
    $h2last='last';
}elseif($header1 > 0){
    $hCols='twelve';
    $h1last='last';
}
```

You can also do it (which might be your originally intention) using only one `&` (bitwise operator):

```
if($header1 & $header2 & $header3 & $header4 > 0){
    $hCols='three';
}elseif($header1 & $header2 & $header3 > 0){
    $hCols='four';
    $h3last='last';
}elseif($header1 & $header2 > 0){
    $hCols='six';
    $h2last='last';
}elseif($header1 > 0){
    $hCols='twelve';
    $h1last='last';
}
```

Comment: this is not waht i am asking for, but it was very helpful